# На месте где должны отображаться символы юникод пишется знак "?", на языке программирования С++

Tags: c++, кодировка, unicode, символы

На языке С++, я создал массив:

```
char alphabet[size_arr_alphabet] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
        'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
        't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '₡', '₢', '₣', '₤', '₥', '₦', '₩', '₪', '€', '₭', '₮', '₱', '₲', '₳', '₴', '₵', '₶', '₷', '₸',
        '₹', '₺', '₻', '₼', '₾', '₿', 'ɓ', 'ɓ', 'm̥', 'ɱ', 'ⱱ', 'β', 'ȶ', 'ȡ', 'ɟ', 'ʄ', 'ȵ', 'ɲ', 'ɕ', 'ʑ', 'ç', 'ʝ', 'ȴ', 'ʎ', 'ʍ', 'ɣ',
        'ʁ', 'ħ', 'ʕ', 'ʢ', 'ɧ', 'ʐ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' };
```

Но при выводе этого массива в консоль, я получаю следующее:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz????????И???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

То есть на месте мне нужных символов отображается знак вопроса "?", как это исправить, как мне правильно вывести эти символы в консоль?

Comment: Cимволы юникода не могут хранится в `char`, для этого есть `wchar_t`. А символы расширенного юникода, такие как ``, обычно не могут хранится и в `wchar_t`. И тут придется использовать строки. Вывод всего этого в консоль - отдельная тема. Да, и всякие строковые функции и классы, типа `std::strlen` или `std::string`, с юникодом работают неверно. Так что если собираетесь плотно работать с юникодом, то сразу ставьте библиотеку ICU.

Comment: Как минимум должен быть `wchar_t` (или другой юникодный тип) вместо `char`, юникодные символы нужно инициализировать как `L'A'`, ну и дальше уже нужно смотреть как вы выводите.

Comment: если придираться, то wchar_t - это не "юникодный тип", это просто "широкий символ". Для хранения юникода наиболее подходящим будет любой 4байтный тип.  А вот уже при выводе конвертировать в нужный формат.

Comment: Неужели компилятор не завалил вас предупреждениеми что данные не помещаются в `char`? Не верю.